# efficient way to change values in python

Tags: python

I am looking for an efficient way to update certain values. The current data structure I am using is a list, but I am open to other suggestions if they are faster.

I'd like to find all values that match `0`, and change those values to `1`

```
L = [1 ,2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 0]
index = [i for i, x in enumerate(L) if x == 0]
index
[6, 8]

for x in index:
    L[x] = 1
L
[1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Is it important that the list is modified in place or would `[x if x != 0 else 1 for x in L]` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless something you did not disclose is preventing it, just build a new list to which you reassign the name `L`.

Very explicit:

```
>>> L = [1 ,2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 0]
>>> L = [x if x != 0 else 1 for x in L]
>>> L
[1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

A little less explicit:

```
>>> L = [1 ,2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 0]
>>> L = [x if x else 1 for x in L]
>>> L
[1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

Or for the cool kids:

```
>>> L = [1 ,2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 0]
>>> L = [x or 1 for x in L]
>>> L
[1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

If you need to mutate `L` in-place use `L[:]` on the left side of the `=` sign.

Alternative in-place operation with numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> L = np.array([1 ,2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 0])
>>> L[L == 0] = 1
>>> L
array([1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using [numpy](https://numpy.org/), you can leverage its fancy [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays):

```py
import numpy as np

L = np.array([1 ,2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 0])

L[L == 0] = 1   # set all values in `L` that are equal to 0 to 1

print(L)        # [1 2 1 3 4 2 1 1 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

In place without numpy:

```
L = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 0]
for idx, val in enumerate(L):
    if val == 0:
        L[idx] = 1
```